# Which native python modules are written in C?

Tags: python, c

I intend to write a small text editor in python. Therefore I need a fast string manipulation/text processing library, which is preferably written in C for performance reasons.

How do I know which python modules are written in C under the hood?

Comment: Get the python sources and look!  It's a sure bet that all the language string primitives are native code.  Data structures tend to be more important than string primitives for edtiting all but tiny files. I'd spend time investigating that rather than string manipulation.

Comment: Why do you think that «written in C» means «fast»? It could be, of course, but could be extremely slow, no matter what language it is written in.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f17647ce8f8a

Comment: almost all the system ones (file access, networking, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Gene recommended, the best way is to look at the sources and find out which module are implemented in C.

You can check the `__file__` module's attribute :

```
>>> import math
>>> print(math.__file__)
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
```

In this example, it's a `.so` file which has been loaded, therefore this module is implemented in a compiled language (most probably in C).

Comment: Does python use any other compiled (to .so) languages?